# query a specific multivalue field irespective to main entity

Tags: solr

So I have two table in my database.

1. user (user_id pk,user_name,....).
2. education(id pk, user_id, college_name).

and following is the index data of solr storing.

```
docs": [
      {
        "name": "Deepesh",
        "id": "1",
        "college_name": [
          "Jamnakhal",
          "Messmore",
          "IMS"
        ],
        "_version_": 1541716111356067800
      },
      {
        "name": "Uniyal",
        "id": "2",
        "college_name": [
          "J. I. C.",
          "ABC",
          "BCD"
        ],
        "_version_": 1541716111356067800
      },
```

The full data searching is ok, but now I have 1 more requirment for autofill search box for college_name, so I am using **EdgeNGramFilterFactory** is solr for **college_name** column and also multiValue is true.

but now when I am trying to search **J**, it returning me the array of all the college name corresponding to user.

this is ok in which term I have stored data in solr.
but how can I solve my 2nd problem for autoFill, if I search college name **J** then it should return me only college names.

**docs": [
      {
        "college_name": "Jamnakhal"
        "*version*": 1541716111356067800
      },
      {
        "college_name": "J. I. C."
        "*version*": 1541716111356067801
      },**

Answer (score 0):

Solr return matching documents ,in above case if collage_name match with  Jamnakhal  then this will return document 1 or spacefic field not only Jamnakhal .

Comment: So, How can I achieve this. If we need only different college names.